# about converting binary numbers of length 64 to decimal in php

Tags: php

I tried to convert a 64-bit binary to decimal.

For example with input like this :

```
"0011000000110000100000011001110011100011000111101110001101001011"
```

I should obtain this output :

```
"‭3472417823527985995‬"
```

But the results obtained are inconsistent with expectations. The result obtained from the example input is

```
"3472417823527986176",
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$b = '0011000000110000100000011001110011100011000111101110001101001011';
echo sprintf("%.0f", bindec($b));
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question. So, what do you want, a solution or an explanation?

Comment: Have you tried `echo bindec($b);`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Negative 64bit Decimal Number to Binary in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699613/negative-64bit-decimal-number-to-binary-in-php)

Comment: What is the OS and PHP version you are using?

Comment: Also please read the [float precision documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

Comment: Thank you,I tried to follow Nigel Ren's words and got the correct result.